# Make first item's class active with Twitter Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to get twitter carousel work properly:

I would like to add the .active class to the first .item div.

```
  .carousel-inner
    - @photos.each do |photo, index|
      .item{ class: "#{ "active" if index == 0 }"}
        = image_tag(photo.image_url, class: "carousel-photo")
```

This doesn't work, because it doesn't add the .active class to the first element of the loop.
How do I add the .active class only to the first element of the loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got the answer:

the **.each_with_index** method needs to be used here:

```
  .carousel-inner
    - @photos.each_with_index do |photo, index|
      .item{ class: "#{ "active" if index == 0 }"}
        = image_tag(photo.image_url, class: "carousel-photo")
```

Answer (score 4):

I did mind similar but instead I did it like this:

```
 <% @user.user_images.each_with_index do |info, index| %>
    <div class="item
    <% if index == 0 %>
       active
    <% end %>

    ">
```